# Soma de Valores dentro de Listas Compostas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tenho uma dúvida sobre como somar determinados valores em Listas Compostas. E queria saber que há um método rápido para isso mesmo.

```
lista_total = []
d = 0

while True:
    nome = str(input('Nome: '))
    lista_total.append(list())
    lista_total[d].append(nome)

    nota1 = int(input('Nota 1: '))
    lista_total[d].append(nota1)

    nota2 = int(input('Nota 2: '))
    lista_total[d].append(nota2)

    d += 1
    question = str(input('Quer continuar? [S/N] '))
 
    if question not in 'Ss':
        break

print('-=' * 30)
print('No. Nome          MÉDIA')
print('-' * 10)
for c in range(0, d):
    print(f'{c} ')      # Média ficará à frente de {c}
```

Exemplo de Output:

```
nº    Nome      Média
0     Ana       15.7
1     João      20.0
2     André     10.0
```

Queria saber se dá para pegar na "lista_total" e encontrando a outra lista de índice 0 por exemplo e somar os valores que estão nos índices 1 e 2 (pois o 0 é o nome da suposta pessoa) e posteriormente dividí-los por 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, você não precisa deste índice `d`. Basta ler os dados e no final você adiciona tudo na `lista_total` de uma vez. Como os dados são de tipos diferentes (um nome que é uma string e várias notas que são números), costuma-se usar [tuplas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple) em vez de listas (claro que com listas também funciona, mas ao usar tuplas você já indica - para qualquer um que for mexer no código, inclusive você mesmo - que possivelmente terão dados de tipos diferentes ali).

Enfim, para ler os dados, poderia ser assim:

```
lista_total = []
while True:
    nome = input('Nome: ')
    nota1 = int(input('Nota 1: '))
    nota2 = int(input('Nota 2: '))

    lista_total.append((nome, [nota1, nota2]))
    if input('Quer continuar? [S/N] ').lower() != 's':
        break
```

Repare nos parênteses da expressão `(nome, [nota1, nota2])`: isso cria uma tupla contendo o nome na primeira posição e a lista com as notas na segunda posição. À primeira vista pode parecer que estes parênteses são redundantes, mas não são. Se você fizesse apenas `lista_total.append(nome, [nota1, nota2])`, estaria passando 2 parâmetros para `append` (o nome e a lista de notas) e isso daria erro porque `append` só recebe um parâmetro. Colocando esses parênteses, eu crio a tupla, que é o que será inserido na lista.

No fim, `lista_total` possuirá várias tuplas, e cada uma dessas tuplas terá o nome na primeira posição e a lista de notas na segunda.

Repare também que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então não precisa fazer `str(input(etc...))`, é redundante e desnecessário. Por fim, usei [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) para transformar a opção "Quer continuar" em minúscula, assim você só precisa compará-la com `'s'`.

---

Em seguida, para imprimir, basta usar [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para percorrer a lista juntamente com os índices. Depois, para cada tupla contida na lista, pegue o primeiro elemento (que será o nome), e o segundo (a lista com as notas) e imprima as informações. Para calcular a média, basta dividir a soma das notas (usando [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)) pela quantidade (usando [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), que pega o tamanho da lista):

```
print('-=' * 15)
alinhamento = '{:<5}{:<20}{}'
print(alinhamento.format('nº','Nome', 'Média'))
print('-' * 30)
for i, dados in enumerate(lista_total):
    notas = dados[1]
    print(alinhamento.format(i, dados[0], sum(notas) / len(notas)))
```

Também usei as [opções de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) para deixar os dados alinhados: `<5` alinha à direita com 5 posições (preenchendo as posições não utilizadas com espaços), e `<20` alinha à direita com 20 posições (ajuste os valores de acordo com o que você precisar). Exemplo:

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
nº   Nome                Média
------------------------------
0    Fulano de tal       3.5
1    Ciclano de qual     5.5
```

Se quiser, já pode "desmembrar" a tupla em variáveis no próprio `for`:

```
for i, (nome, notas) in enumerate(lista_total):
    print(alinhamento.format(i, nome, sum(notas) / len(notas)))
```